How to get VSCode debugger to work with a makefile?
I have a makefile in VSCode that I am trying to run with the debugger.
In my launch config I have this.
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\main.exe",
            "cwd": "c:\\Users\\sferr\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\dev",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "c:\\Users\\sferr\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\compiler\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
        }
    ]

And I am launching a task with the preLaunchTask which runs my makefile.
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "always"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        }
    ],

The makefile runs fine but the debugger controls will popup and then disappear immediately.  It doesn't attach itself to the executable.
Is there a special way to do this?
